# how can i use MM0 through MM7 registers of my cpu?

Tags: c++, assembly, inline-assembly, x86

i am using Digital-Mars C++ and VC++ 10 compilers and i have masm32 assembler. How can i use the mm0....mm7 64-bit registers to switch their data between eax,eabx 32-bit registers? 
Can i use them in c++ compilers asm{} or _asm{} supply?

Something like this could be useful:

```
mmTo32 eax,mm3
mmTo16 bx,mm6
mmTo8 cl,mm4
ToMM mm2,eax
```

I googled but couldnt find enough.

Thank you.

Comment: Is this just a curiosity thing? There's almost no reason to use MMX when there is SSE.

Comment: Just use the MMX intrinsics for this - they are in `<mmintrin.h>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use SSE2, since XMM is better and supported (thanks to Harold's comment, XMM are not related to MM registers, must have been mixed my mind with AVX/SSE).

See this page from MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dzs626wx(v=vs.71).aspx

All the intrinsics you need are here. They are unrolled to inline assembly by the compiler.

You need the `_mm_loadl_pi` / `_mm_loadh_pi` and `_mm_storel_pi`/`_mm_storeh_pi` to load/store values to/from memory.

Just include the "xmmintrin.h" file and enable SSE code generation in your project options.

Comment: The MM registers are aliased to the floating point stack, not to the lower halves of the XMM registers.

Comment: yes i mean the new big registers. i didnt know which is better and easier accesible

Comment: The new "big" ones are from AVX instruction set. Their are 256-bit sized and they are called YMM (and they actually contain XMM as lower halves)